# If there is any way to create the signed url for whole hls stream folder

Tags: php, amazon-s3, aws-sdk, amazon-cloudfront

If there is any way to create the signed url for whole hls stream folder, beacuse in my case i am using multiple stream variants and master m3u8 file, so can i able to create signed url got whole folder???

Comment: You can use CloudFront signed cookies.